# Stop joint_trajectory_controller execution at rostopic event

Tags: ros, follow-joint-trajectory, ros-control, joint-trajectory-controller, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo.

I am using joint_trajectory_controller to control a single actuated joint robotic hand. After having send a `control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal` to joint_trajectory_controller through an `actionlib::SimpleActionClient<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction>`, I'm listening for an event on a particular topic.

When this event occurs, I would like to interrupt the execution of the previously sent trajectory and stop the hand joint at the current position.

I have tried to get the joint value from the joint state topic and to publish this of the joint_trajectory_controller but this does not stop the execution of the previous trajectory.

I also tried to send an empty goal to the topic `/hand_name/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal` but this didn't work either.

An outline of the code is the following:

```
std::shared_ptr<actionlib::SimpleActionClient<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction>> client;
client = std::make_shared<actionlib::SimpleActionClient<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction>>("/hand_name/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory", true);

if (client->waitForServer(ros::Duration(1,0))){
        control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal joint_goal = create_trajectory_goal(joint_position);
        client->sendGoalAndWait(joint_goal, ros::Duration(0.5));
}

int id = 0;
while(id == 0){
    ROS_INFO("I'm waiting for event!\n");
    std_msgs::Int8::ConstPtr id_ptr;
    id_ptr = ros::topic::waitForMessage<std_msgs::Int8>("/event_topic", n);
    id = id_ptr->data;
        
    if (!id) {
        ROS_INFO("No event yet!\n");
    } else {
        ROS_INFO("Event detected with id %d!\n", id);

        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO STOP THE JOINT TRAJECTORY CONTROLLER AND SEND ANOTHER TRAJECTORY

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285385/stop-joint_trajectory_controller-execution-at-rostopic-event/) by [dhindhimathai](https://answers.ros.org/users/31021/dhindhimathai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> client->sendGoalAndWait(joint_goal, ros::Duration(0.5));
> ```

It will depend on `joint_trajectory_controller` playing nice (ie: be properly implemented, but I believe it is), but if you don't use `client->sendGoalAndWait(..)`, but instead `client->sendGoal(..)`, you don't block and can then use any of `SimpleActionClient::cancel*Goal(..)` methods ([documentation](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html)) to cancel the current goal.

> ```
> int id = 0;
> ```

```
while(id == 0){
    ROS_INFO("I'm waiting for event!\n");
    std_msgs::Int8::ConstPtr id_ptr;
    id_ptr = ros::topic::waitForMessage<std_msgs::Int8>("/event_topic", n);
    [..]
```

Please don't do this. This is explicitly not what `waitForMessage(..)` was created for. Under the hood, you're now creating and destroying `ros::Publisher` instances, which takes time. As they need to resubscribe you run the risk of missing events, undersampling (aliasing) and other nasty effects.

ROS is an event based framework. Subscribe to `/event_topic` in the normal way, and then in your callback check whether you have an active goal (that you sent using `client->sendGoal(..)` earlier). If you don't, return from your callback without doing anything (you could of course also only subcribe to `/event_topic` right before you submit your goal). If there is an active goal, check your threshold (or the `id` if you have to) and then cancel the goal from the msg callback using `client->cancelGoal()`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dhindhimathai](https://answers.ros.org/users/31021/dhindhimathai/) on 2018-03-18**:
Sorry for the delay and thank you so much for the perfect answer. Everything now works fine. Thank you also for the corrections on the `waitForMessage(...)` issue.